# Save MySql function on Sequel Pro MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, sequelpro

I have a function that works inside my script but when I try to run it on my Sequel Pro MariaDB to add it to the function list, I get a bunch of errors.

```
drop function if exists related_count;
create function related_count(parent int(11)) returns int(11)
begin
 declare count int(11) default 0;
 while parent!=0 and count<10 do
  set count=count+1;
  set parent=(select related from category where id=parent);
 end while
 return count
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- You need a pair of `DELIMITER` statements.
- More statements need a terminating `;`.

Look in the docs and this forum for examples of `CREATE FUNCTION`.